# Disable vs readonly dont work for non-interactive but value keeper input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-development-server

I am developing some web interfae, I would like to convert some INPUT elements in non-editable/non-changable but still showing the inputed value. How an be this done?

In Chrome at least, disabled attribute makes the inputed value disappear (unmarked checkboxes, non-filled radio buttons) but readonly label allows user to keep changing values. Why? Is this a Chrome thing? Whats the best wa for simply not-allowing interaction but mantaining and showing the preselected value so far?

**EDIT**: I am using jQuery´s

```
$('#deForm :input').attr('readonly',true);
```

and

```
$('#deForm :input').attr('disabled',true);
```

for this test. Both seem to be handled ok, since GUI shadows input elements. But none of them shows my expected functionality

**EDIT2**: I also tried to put 'readonly' and 'disabled' as the second argument in jQuery instead of 'true' but it has same effect

**EDIT3**: I also tried to add to readonly.

```
 $('#deForm :input').attr('readonly',true);
 $('#deForm :input').keypress(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
 });
```

but behavior is the same as in plain readonly

Comment: readonly shouldn't let users edit the input. That would sort of defeat the purpose, right? Did you do readonly="readonly"?

Comment: did you try styling the object with `input:disabled`? I haven't had problems with this so far.

Comment: @user1352530 thats because you can't pass true to readonly like that. Instead, you'd do `$('#deForm :input').attr('readonly','readonly');`

Comment: I tried it as you said, but for Chrome it is still the same as ('readonly',true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the `readonly` and `disabled` properties. You can use the `preventDefault` method of the event object.

```
<input type='text' value='something'/>
```

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function(event){
    if (something is true) {
       event.preventDefault()
       // or return false
    } else {
       //
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fKjX/

Comment: interesting way to go about it

Comment: I guess I still need to put attribute disable to true also for achieving my desired functionality, do I?. Could you explain the return false comment? How can I rollback and enable normal eventing behavior with jQuery when I dont want to disable things anymore? Sorry for the questions, I think they are short though :)

Comment: @user1352530 `return false` like the preventDefault prevents the default action of the event, note that when an input is disabled it's value is not sent to the server. You can use an `if` statement for different situations.

Comment: Yes I dont need this params as operatives when submitting the form on readonly mode (disable makes the input info disappear), so the best option is still readonly it for the GUI to show them shadowed or not interactive, plus your function for assuring real non-interactivity. Now I understand return, thanks. The only question missing is how can I drop the listener for the ordinary behavior once I finish my disabled stage? Thanks!

Comment: @user1352530 You are welcome, as I had suggested you can use `if` condition in your event handlers, however one alternative you have is to remove the `disabled` properties on form submission.

Comment: Sorry, I tested it this morning, it is not working. Maybe Chrome's fault?

Comment: I realized now, that probably keypress event is not the best one for handling the input of all inputs caught by jQuerys input selector (includes selects, checkboxes..)

Comment: @user1352530 For checkboxes and radio buttons you should use the `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said readonly didn't work, but I'm guessing you made a mistake on the syntax. What you want is this:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value = "Hi ima txtbox" id="whatever" class="whatever" />
```

Comment: But readonly attribute is not existing in my input. I set it through jQuery dynammiyally, nand Chrome is interpreting it (not as I expect). Unless you appoint me to manually write the attribute in my input anyway